# Twitter app requires python 3.6.13 to run but Dockerfiles' similar alpine version is not working. Running into mismatch of python package

Tags: python, docker, twitter, dockerfile

The Twitter bot app requires python 3.6.13 to run. While dockerizing it, Dockerfile has alpines' python versions which is not meeting my apps requirement.

How can I install python 3.6.13 in a Dockerfile?

For example, in my case, I tried initiating a docker file like this

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

COPY bots/config.py /bots/
COPY bots/stream.py /bots/
COPY requirements.txt /tmp
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /bots
CMD ["python3", "stream.py"]
```

After creating the docker container, the app crashes due to pythons mismatch of versions.

Later I tried this with the version I want:

```
FROM python:3.6.13

COPY bots/config.py /bots/
COPY bots/stream.py /bots/
COPY requirements.txt /tmp
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /bots
CMD ["python3", "stream.py"]
```

the python package is very large unlike alpine provides.

But When I tried this:

```
FROM python:3.6.13-alpine

COPY bots/config.py /bots/
COPY bots/stream.py /bots/
COPY requirements.txt /tmp
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /bots
CMD ["python3", "stream.py"]
```

It looks like it worked as the program started execution but I got another new error which is this:

```
INFO:tweepy.binder:PARAMS: {}
ERROR:root:Error creating API
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 187, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 466, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 320, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 556, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 109, in __call__
    unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), None, r.headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py", line 351, in sign
    ('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py", line 165, in get_oauth_signature
    uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py", line 248, in _render
    request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/utils.py", line 25, in wrapper
    return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/parameters.py", line 53, in prepare_headers
    escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/utils.py", line 50, in escape
    'Got {!r} of type {}.'.format(u, type(u)))
ValueError: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bots/config.py", line 18, in create_api
    api.verify_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 631, in verify_credentials
    )(**kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 189, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 187, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 466, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 320, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 556, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 109, in __call__
    unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), None, r.headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py", line 351, in sign
    ('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py", line 165, in get_oauth_signature
    uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py", line 248, in _render
    request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/utils.py", line 25, in wrapper
    return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/parameters.py", line 53, in prepare_headers
    escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/utils.py", line 50, in escape
    'Got {!r} of type {}.'.format(u, type(u)))
ValueError: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bots/config.py", line 18, in create_api
    api.verify_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 631, in verify_credentials
    )(**kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 189, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stream.py", line 50, in <module>
    main(['485visas', 'extend485', '485visaextension', '485', '485visa',])
  File "stream.py", line 42, in main
    api = create_api()
  File "/bots/config.py", line 21, in create_api
    raise Exception
Exception
```

The config.py file is this:

```
import tweepy
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()

def create_api():
    # TR485Graduate = tweepy.Stream('CONSUMER_KEY_485', 'CONSUMER_SECRET_485', 'ACCESS_TOKEN_485','ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_485' )
    consumer_key = os.getenv("CONSUMER_KEY_485")
    consumer_secret = os.getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET_485")
    access_token = os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_485")
    access_token_secret = os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_485")

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise Exception
    logger.info("API created")
    return api
```

Is there anything that I can do to avoid this exception error?

Later, I tried to add the python version that I want in the requirements.txt file but it didn't work.

I found up a source but couldn't understand but I feel the answer is here, [source](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/importerror-docker/).

Is there any way I can instantiate the python 3.6.13 version in the Dockerfile so that it uniformly supplies this version to the whole image and the app?

Comment: Have you tried the `python:3.6.13-alpine` base image?

Comment: @abhijat I updated the question with python:3.6.13-alpine error. Please check.

Comment: Could you check if your four auth related environment variables are set correctly? It appears that they may be empty. Your dockerfile does not seem to set them, are they set elsewhere? Maybe try logging them to see if they are set correctly.

Comment: I am following this link: https://realpython.com/twitter-bot-python-tweepy/ , could you check in the page how the docker is instantiated with env variables. I am doing it the same way @abhijat

Comment: @abhijat , while I enter the docker run command, I am entering the env variables like its shown in the link that I shared to you above. It looks like it is not the proper way to declare env variables. I am looking for another way. Please share a source if you have a quick way to declare these variables correctly in docker

Comment: Yes, the problem was because of the env variables. I saved all env variables in a 'file.txt' then after the docker build I passed the file while I run the command 'docker run --env-file my-file.txt ' . @abhijat thanks for helping out